# Android avd device stopped working

Tags: android

So today, until now my avd device launched and it didn't have any problem at all. I were updating through Android SDK Manager and launching an app on the same time but when avd device showed up after 1 minute I got an error message that Windows have to close the app.

My current AVD device is custom:

> 900x600  Android 4.3 - API Level 18 Intel Atom Memory Options: Ram:
>   760 VM Heap: 32 Internal Storage: 200 Mib Use Host Gpu (ticked)

When my app was closed I tryed to see if there is any problem at config.ini. And I changed

> ORIGINAL: disk.dataPartition.size=200M 
>   MODIFIED: disk.dataPartition.size=200MB 
>   ORIGINAL: hw.ramSize=760
>   MODIFIED: hw.ramSize=760MB

and tryed to launch it again, but it didn't work and then I checked again from my device manager that RAM didn't have a value!!! Also I tryed to change the resolutionbut it didn't work.

So this is keep happening. Every time I save it and then fix config.ini but emulator stops.

I tryed to use different device from the list, but they didn't launch either.

This the message from my console also:

```
[2014-03-06 12:49:28 - ] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-03-06 12:49:32 - ] ------------------------------
[2014-03-06 12:49:32 - ] Android Launch!
[2014-03-06 12:49:32 - ] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-06 12:49:32 - ] Performing com.example. .MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-06 12:49:32 - ] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVDPanos'
[2014-03-06 12:49:32 - ] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVDPanos'
[2014-03-06 12:49:37 - Emulator] emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
[2014-03-06 12:49:37 - Emulator] HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
[2014-03-06 12:49:37 - Emulator] 
[2014-03-06 12:49:37 - Emulator] emulator: Open HAX device failed
[2014-03-06 12:49:37 - Emulator] 
[2014-03-06 12:49:38 - Emulator] creating window 0 0 900 600
[2014-03-06 12:49:38 - ] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-03-06 12:49:38 - ] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-03-06 12:49:59 - ] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example. .MainActivity activity launch'!
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed to do what ViramV and Tomazini couple of times (thanks both for your help), but didn't work for me. So I had reinstall the whole package of eclipse from the beginning, because I couldn't find any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

attempts to decrease the ram 528 and uncheck the gpu

and read http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: It didn't work and I have already read about HAXM has nothing to do with that problem because it worked before. Thanks anyway

Comment: got this error this week again, rebooted the machine and it worked, very strange

Answer (score 0):

I also face with the same issue, pap. When I run the project on the emulator, and face with the same issue, I re-run the project (without closing/restarting anything viz. Emulator, Eclipse or the machine). Then it works fine. Try this scenario from your end as well. Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Nope, I tryed couple of times but nothing changed! I don't know maybe do you have another idea?

Comment: @pap: It works for me by doing so what I mentioned. But don't know why it isin't in your case. :(